Factory method 'flyway' threw exception with message: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl with TestContainers
Im using test containers to run integration tests in my springboot application.
When I run my tests, I the below error.
initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception with message: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:tc:postgresql:14-alpine:///expenseTest

It was working a few days back. I have not changed my pom or done any upgrades.
hear is my test class
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:14-alpine:///expenseTest"
})
public class ExpenseControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@Autowired
private ExpenseTransactionRepository repository;

here is my pom
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
        <artifactId>problem-spring-web-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${problem-spring-web.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

the link to my project can be found here https://github.com/manjosh1990/expensemanager
